# Authentication using API endpoint of a different application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, sql-server, spring-boot, axios

I am creating a react web application its logic will be handled by spring boot and the database is SQL server but how can I authenticate using a different API endpoint from a different web application. That is Application 1 has already users registered and has there data I want the same users to be able to use the same credentials to login to this current application 2. The application with the login endpoint was created using .NET and uses SQL Server database. The endpoint has basic auth and using postman I can communicate with the API endpoint and get response.

I tried using axios to fetch the data from the endpoint but am getting CORS error, yet the server is set to accept any incoming requests. I was expecting to be able to fetch data seamlessly from the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have resolve your CORS issue, and for your setup, you have to use your auth application 1 as a service to authenticate and authorize the users of application 2.

Expose apis of app 1, ( login, verify etc apis) and use them in app 2 as a middleware.